# what could be an input that lets you call foo with an array argument t containing more than 15 characters?

Tags: c, buffer-overflow

I would like to find an input or examples of it that still allow us to call the function foo and understand the characteristics of this input

```
    void copy(char b[], int l){
    // b is a string and l is its length
    char t[16] ; // 16 bytes
    int ok ; // 4 bytes
    if (l > 15)
       ok = 0 ;
    else
       ok = 1 ;
    strcpy(t, b) ; // copy b into t
    if (ok==0) { // a buffer overflow did occur in t
        printf("a buffer overflow occured !");
    exit(0);
    } else // t contains no more than 15 characters (no overflow)
       foo(t);
    }
    int main() {
      char buf[24];
      scanf("%s", buf) ;
      copy(buf, strlen(buf)) ; 
      /* ... */
     return 0;
     }
```

Comment: The testing in `copy()` is pointless. A conforming c compiler can deduce that the string input with `scanf()` is at most 15 characters long, and thus `ok` will always be 1.

Comment: Any input of non-zero bytes longer or exact 17 bytes. Assuming that `&ok == t + 16` and that stars are in proper positions.

Comment: @EOF How? The `scanf()` call doesn't specify a maximum length, and the `buf[]` array is 24 chars long.

Comment: @Adrian In `copy()`, the `strcpy()` is executed regardless of how the comparison `l > 15` goes. Since `strcpy()` into a too-small buffer is undefined behavior, the compiler can assume that `l > 15` can *never* be true.

Comment: @KamilCuk I don't understand, why any input of non-zero bytes longer or exact 17 bytes?depends on the organization of memory stack and heap?